# Custom URL using Angular ngResource

Tags: angularjs, api, url, ngresource

I would like to know the best practice for connecting with my API as it works as following:

- GET -> products/list/**latest** -> return list of latest products
- GET -> products/list/**popular** -> return list of popular products
- GET -> products/list/**trending** -> return list of trending products

and then when I want a detail of the each product, it is just:

GET -> products/:id

I got the following code in my services.js:

```
.factory('ProductService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://domainname.com/api/products/:product',{product: "@product"});
})
```

But I really don't know how to access these custom URLs. Can I use the ngResource for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

you can add custom action to ngResources

ie:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);


app.factory('ProductService', function($resource) {

  var actions = {

    'latest': {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/products/latest '

    },

    'popular': {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/products/popular'

    },

    'trending': {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/products/trending '

    }


  };

  var ProductService = $resource('/api/products/:productId', {ProductId: '@id'}, actions);

  return ProductService;

});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ProductService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  ProductService.latest();
  ProductService.popular();
  ProductService.trending();
  ProductService.query();
  ProductService.get({id: 1});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```